# How to convert all the printf-styles in a module to formatting style in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, string-formatting

I am trying to convert a module from python version 2.x to python version 3.x. To do that I am using `2to3` converter. However since I couldn't find any parameter in this converter to change also `%s` or `printf-style` to `str.format()` style I just tried to use [pyupgrade](https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade) package as follows:

> pyupgrade /path/to/myfile.py

However this one also does not make any change. Do you have any idea or suggestion if there is a converter to do this?

Ex.

```
limit=None
ll = 23
limitQuery = 'LIMIT %s,%s'% (limit, ll)
print(limitQuery)
```

after running this command it does not change:
`pyupgrade /Users/Eli/Desktop/test.py`

Comment: (I'm the author of pyupgrade) -- it may support more types of poorly formatted code in the future but for now it is timid: https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade/blob/a5dc2d6c367df8bdac783c4d00cf6dc459f797cf/pyupgrade.py#L937-L940

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The project either has some bugs in this area, or they deliberately ignore code not meeting minimal formatting requirements.

Your sample fails because there are no spaces between the `'` and `%` characters:

```
$ echo "limitQuery = 'LIMIT %s,%s'% (limit, ll)" | pyupgrade -
limitQuery = 'LIMIT %s,%s'% (limit, ll)
```

When you add a space, the project converts the syntax correctly:

```
$ echo "limitQuery = 'LIMIT %s,%s' % (limit, ll)" | pyupgrade -
limitQuery = 'LIMIT {},{}'.format(limit, ll)
```

I've filed a [bug report](https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade/issues/209) with the project. They have confirmed that this is deliberate:

> this is one of the timid parts of pyupgrade, if your code is not well formatted to begin with it won't try to fix it for you.

Hopefully this will be made explicit in the documentation.

To work around this, you could run the [black code formatter](https://github.com/psf/black) on the code first; black will enforce PEP 8 standards and insert that space for you:

```
$ echo "limitQuery = 'LIMIT %s,%s'% (limit, ll)" | black -q - | pyupgrade -
limitQuery = "LIMIT {},{}".format(limit, ll)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used black -q - | pyupgrade - it just reformed my code partially and changed the code from 5k lines to 7k lines which is a bit weird. It seems I should do it manually!

Comment: @ElisaFo: if your project had many long lines of code, black will re-work those to use more lines (increasing readability). PEP 8 also states that top-level objects need to have 2 blank lines in between them, so if you didn't have that already that's another source of more lines I have no idea what your project looks like, so I can only speculate.

Comment: @ElisaFo: generally speaking, black is an *excellent* tool to incorporate in your projects as it ensures your code is uniformly formatted following a long-established standard. Note that those 2k extra lines are not going to add much to the file size really, other than 2k more `\n` characters.

Comment: Yes I guess also black is an excellent tool.  However, even with the black i see most of %s are not changed. Probably this is a problem of `pyupgrade` than my code, that does not support different cases.

Comment: @ElisaFo: is this really that important a change to pursue, however?

Comment: I know it's useless work as far as it does not give any error. But I asked to do that:(